# mpiexec throws error "mkstemp failed No such file or directory"

Tags: android, cross-platform, mpi, mpich, mkstemp

I have cross compiled MPICH for Android and configured it.
It works fine when I spawn a single process as follows

```
$./mpiexec -n 1  -launcher=fork  ./mpi_hello_world                             
Hello world from processor zero, rank 0 out of 1 processors
```

However the Android System responds with following error if  parameter  "n" is greater than 1 as follows :

```
$./mpiexec -n 2  -launcher=fork  ./mpi_hello_world                                         
Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(474).................: 
MPID_Init(190)........................: channel initialization failed
MPIDI_CH3_Init(89)....................: 
MPID_nem_init(272)....................: 
MPIDI_CH3I_Seg_commit(327)............: 
MPIU_SHMW_Seg_create_and_attach(897)..: 
MPIU_SHMW_Seg_create_attach_templ(610): mkstemp failed No such file or directory
```

It may be something related with name of temp file being created  on android  ? Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem or solution is here, but I have to say that the intersection of MPI developers and Android developers at this point is probably just you, so you're going to have to dig down enough to get more information about what MPICH is trying to do so that Android people can help you. Although, a first stab would be that there isn't a program named mkstemp on the Android install you're using. You might need to add a path or figure out an alternative.

Comment: If you build MPICH without shared memory support, then the `mkstemp` functionality shouldn't be needed. Try adding `--with-device=ch3:sock` to your configure line. You will lose performance for intra-node transfers in this build, however.

Comment: @kraffenetti , Thanks for comment, I am already using --with-device=ch3:sock option.

Comment: can you post your `config.log` from the main MPICH directory? `MPID_nem_init(272)` should not occur in a `ch3:sock` build.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on Android file system you do not have /tmp and /dev/shm directories, which are crutial for creating temp files for shared-memory communication. Because of that, mkstemp() will fail. mkdir them while you are su, set up the permissions and ch3:nemesis will work.